# clearTimeout runs but it is not clearing the setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval, clearinterval, cleartimeout

I am trying reload the page after 20 seconds if the search button is not clicked. And the if it is clicked then I want the search to be made every 20 seconds.

The execution enters the `if-else` condition but the `clearTimeout` doesn't seem to be working.

The execution always refreshes the entire page regardless of whether the search is made or not. What am I doing wrong?

```
function init() //runs on application load
{
    //some code
    reload(false);
}
```

EDIT: `inti()` and `search(), reload()` are in separate files and separate folders.

```
function search() //runs when search button is clicked
{
    //some code
    reload(true);
}

function reload(isSearch)
{
    var x = setTimeout( function () { window.location.reload() }, 20 * 1000);
    var y = setInterval( function () { $('#searchButton').click() }, 20 * 1000);

    if(isSearch)
    {
        clearTimeout(x);
    }
    else
    {
        clearInterval(y);
    }
}
```

I also tried to check if `x` and `y` are `undefined` but that didn't work either. Please help.

Comment: if you call `reload(false)` it will never cancel the timeout since `clearTimeout` is never called

Comment: whenever you call reload, another x & y is initiated. So you can't clear the previous x & y when you `search`. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Also is the searchButton a submit button in a form? That will also reload the page and re-initialise the timeouts and intervals

Comment: @mplungjan it is an `ImageButton` in aspx file.

Comment: @nickzoum that's fine and it is working as such. I want clearTimeout(x) to run when it is `reload(true)` but it is not happening.

Comment: @that_noob But if you do `reload(false)` then a `reload(true)` won't reverse that

Comment: @nickzoum when `reload(true)` it goes into `if(isSearch)` so `clearTimeout(x)` happen, right?

Comment: Am I doing some logical error here?

Answer (score 0):

The `x` and `y` variables are scoped to the function (every call to `reload` creates a new `x` and `y`). Try this:

```
let reloadTimeout
let searchInterval

function init () {
  reloadTimeout = setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload() }, 20 * 1000 })
}

function search () {
  clearTimeout(reloadTimeout)
  searchInterval = setInterval(function () { $('#searchButton').click() }, 20 * 1000 })
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention earlier, sorry. The `init()` and `search(), reload()` are in different files and two separate folders. In that case, `reloadTimeout` is unknown to `search()`.

I have edited the question.

Comment: Are you using a bundler?

Comment: I don't see a Bundle.config file in the project so I guess no.